# In Xamarin, how should Behaviors and Commands be used to initiate an action in the ViewModel?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

In short, I've managed to hook up an action to be triggered in my ViewModel following an event off a control in my View using Behaviors and Commands, but this ended up entailing a workaround for a bug in the framework that makes me question if this is even the correct approach for this kind of problem.

In specific, I have some calculation being performed in my ViewModel that I want to perform after the user *finishes* updating an Entry control in my View. I decided this should hang off the Completed event. To accomplish this, I set up my code like so;

EntryCommand.cs

```
namespace SocialStocksCross.Command
{
    public class EntryCommand : ICommand
    {
        public Action _callback;

        public EntryCommand()
        {
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object test)
        {
            return true;
        }
        public void Execute(object test)
        {
            _callback();
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }
}
```

MainPageViewModel.cs

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        CommandVM = new EntryCommand();
        CommandVM._callback = CalculateStuff;
        UpdateLabel();
    }
    private EntryCommand _command;

    public EntryCommand CommandVM
    {
        get
        {
            return _command;
        }
        set
        {
            _command = value;
        }
    }
    
    public void CalculateStuff()
    {
      // does stuff
    }
}
```

My Behavior class was defined like so;

```
namespace SocialStocksCross.Behaviors
{
    class EntryBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty =
               BindableProperty.Create("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(EntryBehavior), null);

        public ICommand Command
        {
            get
            {
                return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
        {
            base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);

            bindable.Completed += OnEntryCompleted;
            // Perform setup
        }

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
        {
            base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
            // Perform clean up
        }

        void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string oldText = e.OldTextValue;
            string newText = e.NewTextValue;
        }

        void OnEntryCompleted(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            if (BindingContext == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            // do something
            if (Command == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            Command.Execute(args);
        }
    }
}
```

And the relevant part of my view was like so;

```
<Entry Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="companySymbol" Text="{Binding CompanySymbol}">
            <Entry.Behaviors>
                <localbehaviors:EntryBehavior Command="{Binding CommandVM, Mode=OneWayToSource}"></localbehaviors:EntryBehavior>
            </Entry.Behaviors>
        </Entry>
```

As far as I could tell from what I could read online, this seemed like it should work, but the Command on the Behavior was never bound to the Command on the ViewModel. After some digging, it turned out the Command's BindingContext was always null, possibly due this bug, though since it's marked as closed I would have thought it would have been fixed...
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2581

What I ended up having to do was manually set the BindingContext of the Behavior in the .cs to inherit from the View's own BindingContext and set up my binding that way. And while my code now *works*, if this hasn't been fixed in the framework, I have to doubt as to whether there's some other way this kind of thing is supposed to be handled and this whole Behavior binding just isn't really recommended?

Comment: did you read the Issue you linked to?  They explain why this BindingContext is null for behaviors and how to work around it.  They aren't going to fix it because it was a specific design decision, not a bug.

Comment: The fact that Stephane Delcroix repeatedly apologises, regrets the decisions made and expresses a desire to hide does make it seem more like it wasn't really a specific decision... or at least not one that they're happy with.

If that's how it's supposed to work, sure, that answers my question,I guess

Comment: @P.Wright Hi, if you have found an answer, you could update it in answer when you have time.